# "Failed to get property: gid" error in geoserver sql view

Tags: geoserver, wfs

I have a postgis data with 777 features. In geoserver, i created a sql view with another table. In the wms request i can see all features, in qgis also i can see all features. but in wfs output as csv or geojson i only get 55 features. On doing wfs with openlayers it gives error

```
<ows:ExceptionReport version="1.0.0"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ows http://localhost:8080/geoserver/schemas/ows/1.0.0/owsExceptionReport.xsd"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows">
  <ows:Exception exceptionCode="NoApplicableCode">
    <ows:ExceptionText>java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to get property: gid
Failed to get property: gid
java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry</ows:ExceptionText>
  </ows:Exception>
</ows:ExceptionReport>
```

Answer (score 1):

**I suspect that** (at least one of) **your features has geometry errors**. Although you have 777 features only 55 of them are properly exported. So it must be a problem beginning with the 56th feature. This is all I can read from your *ExceptionReport*.

In your case, I see two options for you to explore:

`1)` To load your features into [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/) again and go to `Vector > Geometry Tools > Multipart to Singleparts` as in the image below:

[image]

Then save your data in your server, and repeat the wfs output process. If you are not lucky enough, and the error persists, I advise you to `2)` and to perform a geometry validity on your data;

`2)` In [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/) you'll go to `Vector > Geometry Tools > Check geometry validity`:

[image]

If you'll encounter `Geometry errors` (like bellow), you must solve and save them into your database, prior to repeat the wfs outputing.

If these doesn't solve your problem, then check your *GeoServer log* for additional possible causes.